# Getting Props of element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my index file i have this`export const Head = () => <Head siteTitle="Home" />`, in about this `export const Head = () => <Head siteTitle="About" />` and so on...

The thing is that i want to get this value into this script for my head:

```
export const Head = ({ siteTitle }, props) => {

return (
<>
<title>${siteTitle} | Suffix</title>
<meta property="og:locale" content="de_DE" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
</>
```

How To do that?

Comment: There are libraries that do this. Try `react-helmet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the library like [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) to do this for you. If you don't want to use the library, you can do the following as well.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react"

function buildMeta(attributes) {
  const meta = document.createElement("meta")
  for (const key in attributes) {
    meta.setAttribute(key, attributes[key])
  }
  return meta
}

export function Head({ siteTitle, ...props }) {
  // Run on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    document.head.appendChild(buildMeta({
      property: "og:locale",
      content: "de_DE",
    }));

    document.head.appendChild(buildMeta({
      property: "og:type",
      content: "website",
    }));
  }, []);

  // Run whenever "siteTitle" changes
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = siteTitle
  }, [siteTitle]);

  return null;
}
```

The reason you need to add the `meta` tag in the `head` is because browsers only parse `meta` tags from `head` and ignore the tags in `body`. If you add the `meta` tag in return statement from a component, you end up adding it to the `body`.

**Of course this is a very naïve implementation and if your `<Head/>` remounts multiple times, it will append duplicate `meta` tags to the `head`. You can add checks for that. But recommendation is to check out [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) library which does lot of things for you, out-of-the-box.**